# display 0 in the result for no row

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, plsql

i need to write a java program that makes connection to database , the program should prompt user to enter 7 digits ID and then compute the number of occurrences of each letter grade and the total number of grades .

for example: student 12345
A'S :1
B'S : 0
C'S :3
D'S : 0
F'S: O
TOTAL GRADE : 4

my code below is working correctly but the problem is that the result of no row doesn't give me 0 .. e.x : it just give me A, C and it deletes others

so do you have any idea how can i display 0 in the result.

thank u

```
import java.sql.*; // Use classes in java.sql package
import java.util.*;

public class DDBB {

    public static void main (String args []) {
        int a;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a 7 digit Number for StudentID");
        a = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("StudentID" +" "+ a);
        int countgrade ;
        String GRADE1;
        int totalcount;
        Connection conn =null;
        Statement st =null;
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
            // Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            String url ="jdbc:oracle:thin ....";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"user", "password");
            // create a Statement object
            PreparedStatement st1 = conn.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT GRADE, Count(*) AS COUNT1 FROM GRADING WHERE StudentID = ? GROUP BY Grade ORDER BY GRADE");
            st1.setInt(1, a);
            ResultSet S = st1.executeQuery();
            while (S.next()) {
                countgrade = S.getInt("COUNT1");
                GRADE1 = S.getString("GRADE");
                System.out.println(GRADE1 + "'s :"+countgrade+"\n");
            }
            String Q2 ="SELECT COUNT(GRADE) AS COUNT2 FROM GRADING WHERE StudentID = ? ";
            ResultSet S1 = st1.executeQuery(Q2);
            while (S1.next()) {
                totalcount = S1.getInt("COUNT2");
                System.out.println("Total grades:"+ " " + totalcount+"\n");
            }
            S.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                // close the Statement object using the close() method
                if (st != null) {
                    st.close();
                }
                // close the Connection object using the close() method
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this needs some formatting

Comment: @MajidLAISSI can you read the question now?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question to me.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you tell me :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should be using a `for` loop instead of a `while` to print the grades (or maybe just not using a loop).

Why not do something like this psuedocode:

```
int A = B = C = D = F = 0;
/* Get results as you already are, stored in result set s */
while( s.next() )
{
    string grade = s.GetString("GRADE");
    if( grade == "A" )
        A = s.GetInt("COUNT1")
    if( grade == "B" )
        B = s.GetInt("Count1")
    /*etc*/
}
```

At the end of the while loop, just output "A's: " + A + " B's:" ...

And when you display your final number of grades, just display A + B + C + D + F.

This cuts it down to one SQL query, and it will always show each letter grade.

Comment: There are, of course, places where this could be tightened up.  I've left that as an exercise for you len - What I put in above will work, but it could work better or be more cleanly read with a bit of work.  Enjoy!